# How do I determine the web origin folder of a ClickOnce application?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have an C# application that is deployed as a ClickOnce application. The installation files can live in one of three possible folders on our web server: Alpha, Beta, and Production. The user addresses the appropriate location in IE to start the application: www.foo.com/Alpha, www.foo.com/Beta, or www.foo.com/Prod. In testing, we copy the installation files to Alpha first, then (when it passes testing) to Beta, then (when it passes user acceptance), to production. There is no recompilation.

What I want to know is whether there is any way the C# code can know *at runtime* which version it is: Alpha, Beta, or Production. It would be based only on which folder the ClickOnce installation files were located in. Remember that there has been no recompilation.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: From where you want to know the location? From inside the application code itself or some other application needs to know about the location?

Comment: What have you tried that's returning the wrong location? There are several methods to get an Assembly's location.

Comment: I need to know within the application code itself. Specifically, I need to know so that I can select which instance of SQL Server (not which database within an instance) my application is to use.

Comment: I don't need to know the Assembly's _current_ location, I need to know its installer's original URL (or location).

Comment: @DavidStowell: Okay, in your post, you say that the application is "started" from IE. I presume from your comment that you meant "installed", and that there is no running presence on the server.

Comment: @DavidStowell: You could use a custom element in your ClickOnce manifest for each folder. You wouldn't have to re-compile, but you would have to re-sign the manifest in each folder.

Comment: No, there is no running presence on the server. Questions: Could a custom element be manipulated purely by automated means (we are using Jenkins to move the versions about)? Can the resigning be done through such a means? And finally, how is that element accessed in application code? This sounds promising, but it's a matter logistical details.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a custom manifest element, but it will require some post-build processing.

The application can access the manifest file simply by opening a file stream on the `AppName.exe.manifest` file, and parsing the XML to locate and read the custom element. The manifest is deployed to the same directory as the executable.

When the application files are copied to a web server folder, simply modify the manifest to append the custom element (it could technically even be an XML comment, parsed with simple text comparison, if you don't want to use an XML parser).

After the manifest is modified (in each folder), it will have to be re-signed with the mage.exe signing tool.

You can automate this with a shell script fairly easily. On the whole, however, it would probably be a lot simpler to just build different actual versions.

Comment: That does seem like a lot of work. At the same time, I want Alpha, Beta and Prod to be exactly the same, just addressing different instances of SQL Server. I definitely don't want the version number to change. I figured that if I put all the connection strings in the app and somehow determined which one to use based on which URL was called by the user, I'd be good. That's apparently not accessible. Am I stuck recompiling? If so, what can I do to do minimal damage to the app from type to type?

Comment: @DavidStowell: I don't understand what you mean by "damage", but it's best not to try to have extended discussion in comments. You might want to post another question about compiling your project that covers those issues.

Comment: "Damage" might be a bit strong - I'm referring to changes to the app that would make it different than what had passed testing at a previous level. So unless someone else chimes in with a different observation, I'll proceed on the assumption that simply moving an app installation from one folder to another will not be detectable by the installed result without great effort. Therefore, I'll research recompilation with minimal change as a method for solving my problem. Thank you for your feedback.